# Increasing and Decreasing function - calculus

Tags: calculus

Find critical numbers and the open intervals on which the function is increasing or decreasing.

$$f(x)=$$$$\frac{x}{x^2+9}$$

I think I needed to use the quotient rule so i applied it and got up to :

$$\frac{-x^2+9}{(x^2+9)^2}$$

if this is right, what do I need to do next?

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly used the quotient rule to find the derivative or gradient of $f(x)$.

The question then asks for two things: critical points and open intervals on which the function is either increasing or decreasing.

For any point $x$ in the domain of the function, one of three things is true. Either:

1. $f'(x) > 0$, i.e. the function is increasing;
2. $f'(x) = 0$, i.e. the function is a critical point;
3. $f'(x) < 0$, i.e. the function is decreasing.

You can find the points which fall into category 2; any other points will fall into open intervals, each of which will either satisfy category 1, *increasing*, or category 3, *decreasing*.

If you take your domain, the reals, and remove the critical points, you'll be left with just open intervals. Each of these has $f(x)$ either increasing on all of it or decreasing on all of it. This is because your derivative is a continuous function, meaning that it can't jump from being negative (category 3) to being positive (category 1) without being 0 at some point in between.

Answer (score 0):

You're about halfway there.  Now determine when the derivative is zero; these are the critical points.  Since the denominator is always positive (for real $x$), this amounts to determining when the numerator is zero.  Finally, plug in some values of $x$ between the critical points to identify where the derivative is positive or negative, and hence, where the curve is increasing or decreasing.